# Elegant way to add elements in a list if the elements are not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following codes which add `a` and `b` into `my_input` when they are not None. The code works fine, but I am wondering is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

```
if a is not None and b is not None
    my_input = [
        [a, b]
    ] + my_lib.get_my_list()
else:
    my_input = my_lib.get_my_list()
```

Comment: Was one of these answers what you were looking for? If not, could you provide some more guidance as to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
[[a, b] if a is not None and b is not None else my_lib.my_list()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find a new way to do this:

```
my_input = []
(a is not None and b is not None) and my_input.append([a, b])
my_input = my_input + my_lib.get_my_list()
```